# New rows being the combination of old rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe that looks like which records races between different F1 racers indexed by their `Racer_Number`

```
Racer_Number    Meeting_Number  Date        Runners a       b
1               1               29/11/2015  4       0.002   0.004
2               1               29/11/2015  4       0.088   0.058
3               1               29/11/2015  4       0.215   0.177
4               1               29/11/2015  4       0.215   0.194
1               2               29/11/2015  3       0.025   0.019
2               2               29/11/2015  3       0.364   0.388
3               2               29/11/2015  3       0.024   0.041
1               3               29/11/2015  5       0.001   0.003
2               3               29/11/2015  5       0.004   0.005
3               3               29/11/2015  5       0.002   0.003
4               3               29/11/2015  5       0.010   0.011
5               3               29/11/2015  5       0.051   0.096
```

and I want to generate a new dataframe with rows be the combination of the racers in the same race, so for example for meeting 1 with 4 races 1,2,3,4, the rows are 1_2,1_3,1_4,2_3,2_4,3_4. And I want to generate two new columns called `aa` and `ab`, where the value of `aa` in row i_j is the product of `a` of i and `a` of j, similarly, the value of `ab` in row i_j is the product of `a` of i and `b` of j. So the desired outcome looks like

```
Racer_Combination   Meeting_Number  Date        Runners aa          ab
1_2                 1               29/11/2015  4       0.000191    0.000127
1_3                 1               29/11/2015  4       0.000468    0.000386
1_4                 1               29/11/2015  4       0.000468    0.000423
2_3                 1               29/11/2015  4       0.018793    0.015513
2_4                 1               29/11/2015  4       0.018802    0.016991
3_4                 1               29/11/2015  4       0.046069    0.041631
1_2                 2               29/11/2015  3       0.009241    0.009839
1_3                 2               29/11/2015  3       0.000599    0.001033
2_3                 2               29/11/2015  3       0.008605    0.014848
1_2                 3               29/11/2015  5       0.000004    0.000006
1_3                 3               29/11/2015  5       0.000002    0.000004
1_4                 3               29/11/2015  5       0.000012    0.000013
1_5                 3               29/11/2015  5       0.000062    0.000115
2_3                 3               29/11/2015  5       0.000006    0.000013
2_4                 3               29/11/2015  5       0.000036    0.000041
2_5                 3               29/11/2015  5       0.000191    0.000355
3_4                 3               29/11/2015  5       0.000015    0.000017
3_5                 3               29/11/2015  5       0.000079    0.000146
4_5                 3               29/11/2015  5       0.000499    0.000931
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution, based on [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations
g = df.groupby('Meeting_Number')

(pd.concat(
    [x[['Meeting_Number', 'Date', 'Runners']].head(1)
     .assign(Racer_Combination = f'{y[0]}_{y[1]}', 
             aa = x.loc[x['Racer_Number'].eq(y[0]),'a'].iloc[0] * 
             x.loc[x['Racer_Number'].eq(y[1]),'a'].iloc[0],
             ab = x.loc[x['Racer_Number'].eq(y[0]),'a'].iloc[0] *
             x.loc[x['Racer_Number'].eq(y[1]),'b'].iloc[0])     
     for _, x in g for y in combinations(x['Racer_Number'], 2)]))
```

Output:

```
   Meeting_Number        Date  Runners Racer_Combination        aa        ab
0               1  29/11/2015        4               1_2  0.000176  0.000116
0               1  29/11/2015        4               1_3  0.000430  0.000354
0               1  29/11/2015        4               1_4  0.000430  0.000388
0               1  29/11/2015        4               2_3  0.018920  0.015576
0               1  29/11/2015        4               2_4  0.018920  0.017072
0               1  29/11/2015        4               3_4  0.046225  0.041710
4               2  29/11/2015        3               1_2  0.009100  0.009700
4               2  29/11/2015        3               1_3  0.000600  0.001025
4               2  29/11/2015        3               2_3  0.008736  0.014924
7               3  29/11/2015        5               1_2  0.000004  0.000005
7               3  29/11/2015        5               1_3  0.000002  0.000003
7               3  29/11/2015        5               1_4  0.000010  0.000011
7               3  29/11/2015        5               1_5  0.000051  0.000096
7               3  29/11/2015        5               2_3  0.000008  0.000012
7               3  29/11/2015        5               2_4  0.000040  0.000044
7               3  29/11/2015        5               2_5  0.000204  0.000384
7               3  29/11/2015        5               3_4  0.000020  0.000022
7               3  29/11/2015        5               3_5  0.000102  0.000192
7               3  29/11/2015        5               4_5  0.000510  0.000960
```

Answer (score 2):

You can merge dataframe with itself, filter only pairs where left `Racer_Number` is greater than right `Racer_Number`, then calculate new columns and drop the redundant ones:

```
df_union = df.merge(
    df.drop("Runners", axis=1),
    how="inner",
    on=["Meeting_Number", "Date"]
)

df_union = df_union[df_union["Racer_Number_x"] < df_union["Racer_Number_y"]]
df_union["Racer_Combination"] = [f"{x}_{y}" for x, y in zip(df_union["Racer_Number_x"], df_union["Racer_Number_y"])]
df_union["aa"] = df_union["a_x"] * df_union["a_y"]
df_union["ab"] = df_union["a_x"] * df_union["b_y"]

df_union = df_union \
    [["Racer_Combination", "Meeting_Number", "Date", "Runners", "aa", "ab"]] \
    .reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_union)
```

Output:

```
   Racer_Combination  Meeting_Number        Date  Runners        aa        ab
0                1_2               1  29/11/2015        4  0.000176  0.000116
1                1_3               1  29/11/2015        4  0.000430  0.000354
2                1_4               1  29/11/2015        4  0.000430  0.000388
3                2_3               1  29/11/2015        4  0.018920  0.015576
4                2_4               1  29/11/2015        4  0.018920  0.017072
5                3_4               1  29/11/2015        4  0.046225  0.041710
6                1_2               2  29/11/2015        3  0.009100  0.009700
7                1_3               2  29/11/2015        3  0.000600  0.001025
8                2_3               2  29/11/2015        3  0.008736  0.014924
9                1_2               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000004  0.000005
10               1_3               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000002  0.000003
11               1_4               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000010  0.000011
12               1_5               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000051  0.000096
13               2_3               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000008  0.000012
14               2_4               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000040  0.000044
15               2_5               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000204  0.000384
16               3_4               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000020  0.000022
17               3_5               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000102  0.000192
18               4_5               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000510  0.000960
```

Although, I'm getting slightly different `aa` and `ab` values from yours, so maybe the calculations should be tweaked a bit.

Comment: Merging is a short-code approach, but the drawback is that you produce all permutations, including the non-needed one, which creates a 2x larger intermediate.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to only generate the necessary combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations


cols = ['Meeting_Number', 'Date', 'Runners']
other_cols = df.columns.difference(cols)

def combine(g):
    a, b = map(list, zip(*combinations(g.index, 2)))
    return (pd
           .concat([df.loc[a, ].reset_index(drop=True),
                    df.loc[b, other_cols].reset_index(drop=True).add_suffix('_')
                   ], axis=1)
           .assign(Racer_Combination=lambda d: d['Racer_Number'].astype(str)
                                          +'_'+d['Racer_Number_'].astype(str),
                   aa=lambda d: d['a']*d['a_'],
                   ab=lambda d: d['a']*d['b_']
                  )
            [['Racer_Combination', 'Meeting_Number', 'Date', 'Runners', 'aa', 'ab']]
        )

out = df.groupby(['Meeting_Number', 'Date', 'Runners'], group_keys=False).apply(combine)
```

Output:

```
  Racer_Combination  Meeting_Number        Date  Runners        aa        ab
0               1_2               1  29/11/2015        4  0.000176  0.000116
1               1_3               1  29/11/2015        4  0.000430  0.000354
2               1_4               1  29/11/2015        4  0.000430  0.000388
3               2_3               1  29/11/2015        4  0.018920  0.015576
4               2_4               1  29/11/2015        4  0.018920  0.017072
5               3_4               1  29/11/2015        4  0.046225  0.041710
0               1_2               2  29/11/2015        3  0.009100  0.009700
1               1_3               2  29/11/2015        3  0.000600  0.001025
2               2_3               2  29/11/2015        3  0.008736  0.014924
0               1_2               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000004  0.000005
1               1_3               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000002  0.000003
2               1_4               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000010  0.000011
3               1_5               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000051  0.000096
4               2_3               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000008  0.000012
5               2_4               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000040  0.000044
6               2_5               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000204  0.000384
7               3_4               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000020  0.000022
8               3_5               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000102  0.000192
9               4_5               3  29/11/2015        5  0.000510  0.000960
```